What happened to Oracle's COUNTDISTINCT() function?
I need the count of unique values, and am trying to use Oracle's COUNTDISTINCT() function to obtain that:
select COUNTDISTINCT(a.m_label)
        from user_rep a, user_group_rep b, trn_grp_rep c
        where b.m_user_id = a.m_reference
...

This results in ORA-00904: "COUNTDISTINCT": invalid identifier... Using plain COUNT() works, but is not returning correct results.
What am I doing wrong? What'd be an efficient work-around?

That documentation is not about Oracle database. Such function never existed in Oracle database. It should be count(distinct a.m_label).

Thanks. What is the documentation about, though, if it is not about Oracle database?

@MikhailT. E93962_01 is the documentation of "Oracle Big Data Discovery".
